# Issue Reversing Array of Objects with JS

Tags: javascript, object, reverse

I'm parsing JSON and getting an array of objects with javascript.  I've been doing this to then append an element for each object:

```
for(o in obj){ ... }
```

But I realized that for a certain situation I want to go backwards through the array.  So I tried this before the for loop:

```
obj = obj.reverse();
```

However this isn't reversing the order of the objects in the array.  I could simply put a count variable in the for loop to manually get the reverse, but I'm puzzled as to why reverse doesn't seem to work with object arrays.

Comment: `obj = obj.reverse()` is unecessary, because `reverse` is a mutator method. You can simply do `obj.reverse()`.

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) it should work. Note that you should **not** iterate over an array with `for...in`. Use a normal `for` loop, then you could simply iterate over from `arr.length` to `0` as well. It does not matter at all which data types are contained in the array. If you actually have an object and not an array then you cannot reverse the order anyways (there is no order). Please provide the value of `obj`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "object array" in JavaScript.  There are Objects, and there are Arrays (which, of course, are also Objects).  Objects have properties and the properties are not ordered in any defined way.

In other words, if you've got:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

there's no guarantee that a `for ... in` loop will visit the properties in the order "a", "b", "c".

Now, if you've got an *array of objects* like:

```
var arr = [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ];
```

then that's an ordinary array, and you can reverse it.  The `.reverse()` method mutates the array, so you don't re-assign it. If you *do* have an array of objects (or a real array of any sort of values), then you should *not* use `for ... in` to iterate through it.  Use a numeric index.

*edit* — it's pointed out in a helpful comment that `.reverse()` does return a reference to the array, so reassigning won't hurt anything.

Comment: ... additionally (because of this lack of guarantee!) an `Object` has no method `reverse()`, where-as an [`Array` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Comment: … therefore you cannot reverse the order because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @FelixKling ah OK I was just about to try that in the console. The MDN page doesn't say what the return value is, I don't think. (I'll update it.) *edit* oops yes it does say.  OK then :-)

Comment: It is definitely an array: [Object, Object, Object].  Good to know that it mutates the array, I didn't realize.  Why should I use a numeric index to iterate in the for loop?

Comment: @captDaylight well you can run into problems with `for ... in` because it picks up *all* the properties of the object, not just the numerically-indexed ones. Plus, of course, you're guaranteed to see the numerically-indexed parameters in the right order when you're explicitly defining the "right" order with the way you increment or decrement through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `for (o in obj)` doesn't iterate the array as an array, but as an object. It iterates the properties in the object, which also includes the members in the array, but they are iterated in order of name, not the order that you placed them in the array.

Besides, you are using the `reverse` method wrong. It reverses the array in place, so don't use the return value:

```
obj.reverse();
```

Comment: When you say that the `for ... in` loop goes in name order, is that a statement of how some/most/all browsers behave?  My impression is that the spec explicitly doesn't define the ordering ...

Comment: @Pointy: You are right, it does not define it. Browsers do behave differently. Some are iterating over the properties in insertion order (I think Firefox does), whereas others (I think Chrome) first iterate over numerical properties and then alphanumeric ones... or something like that. You definitely cannot rely on the order across different browsers.